# Building the Release configuration of app on macOS does not generate a valid IPA file

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to deploy an FMX app to the macOS App Store, but my release build doesn't seem to generate the expected project output file.

I have activated the `Release` build configuration. The macOS 64 bit target platform is active and I've activated and configured the `Application Store` configuration (I've set up the certificates and codesign seems to run correctly).

I'm testing this in a simple test application for which the deployment tab looks like this:

[image: deployment]

The ProjectOutput file has a local name of `deploymactestproj` and this is indeed the file generated. However I was excepting `deploymactestproj.ipa` to be generated.

When I run

`xcrun altool --upload-app --type macos --file deploymactestproj --username <username> --password <password>`

to upload the app, I get:

> The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive. Please make sure deploymactestproj.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive. Unable to validate your application. (-20008)

Which seems logical as `deploymactestproj` does not seem to be an IPA file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be expecting "deploymactestproj.pkg" for a MacOS target, not an .ipa file.  The file with no file extension is the project's executable binary, not the package that altool expects.

That file "deploymactestproj.pkg" should be in the root of your profile-directory which is a directory under your scratch-dir.

PAServer's output of the productbuild command line should give you the exact location of the .pkg file.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much, very insightful. I was kinda blindsighted by the error message mentioning an ipa archive. I should have inspected the build messages in Delphi more closely to see what paserver was outputting.